# Devise Invitable is modifying existing users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

**CONTEXT**

I'm using devise_invitable to allow a user (with an admin role) to register another user in my app.

*User objects* have an email, password, token (random string), role (also string) and an associated *HealthRecord object* which has name, last name, dni (personal id) plus some extra info

**PROBLEM**

For some reason, when I input an existing email, I get an error (which is intended validation) but it also destroys the HealthRecord associated with the user who has that existing email.

**CODE**

**This is what my console shows upon trying to create the user with existing email**

```
Started POST "/users/invitation" for ::1 at 2021-11-26 10:04:15 -0300
Processing by Users::InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"paciente1@example.com", "role"=>"Paciente", "health_record_attributes"=>{"residencia"=>"Cementerio", "nombre"=>"overriding", "apellido"=>"test", "dni"=>"123456789", "risk"=>"0", "birth"=>"1999-02-12"}}, "commit"=>"Registrar"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "paciente1@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  HealthRecord Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "health_records".* FROM "health_records" WHERE "health_records"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  HealthRecord Destroy (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "health_records" WHERE "health_records"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (207.2ms)  commit transaction
  User Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? AND "users"."id" != ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "paciente1@example.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  HealthRecord Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "health_records" WHERE "health_records"."dni" = ? LIMIT ?  [["dni", "123456789"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/invitations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  HealthRecord Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "health_records".* FROM "health_records" WHERE "health_records"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/users/invitations/new.html.erb:18
```

The view to generate the new user

```
<h2>Registro excepcional</h2>

<%= form_for(setup_user(resource), as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>

  <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label field %><br />
      <%= f.text_field field, class: 'form-control'%> 
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value=>"Paciente"%> 
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :health_record do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.hidden_field :residencia, :value=>current_user.health_record.residencia%> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label "Nombre" %><br/>
      <%= ff.text_field :nombre, class: 'form-control',:required => true%> 
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label "Apellido" %><br/>
      <%= ff.text_field :apellido, class: 'form-control',:required => true%> 
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label "DNI" %><br/>
      <%= ff.text_field :dni, class: 'form-control',:required => true%> 
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label "Es de riesgo:",:required => true %>
      <%= ff.check_box :risk  %> 
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= ff.label "Fecha de nacimiento:"%><br/>
        <%= ff.date_field :birth, class: 'form-control',:required => true%> 
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <br/>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Registrar" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The user model **which has validate_on_invite**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:token,:email], :validate_on_invite => true
  has_many :comprobantes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :health_record, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :TurnoAsignado, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :TurnoNoAsignado, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  
  before_save :init

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :health_record

  def init()
    if self.token.nil?
      self.token = (rand()*1000000).to_i
    end
  end

end
```

The HealthRecord model

```
class HealthRecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :dni, presence: true
  validates :dni, uniqueness: true
  validates :nombre, presence: true
  validates :apellido, presence: true
  validates :birth, presence: true
  before_save :upcase_content
  
  def upcase_content
      self.nombre=self.nombre.downcase
      self.apellido=self.apellido.downcase
      self.nombre=self.nombre.split(/ |\_/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
      self.apellido=self.apellido.split(/ |\_/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  end

end
```

The invitation controller (it's pretty much default I just added parameters and an after_path)

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
   
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

    #Permit the new params here.
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:invite, keys: [
        :token,
        :role,
        health_record_attributes: [
            :apellido, 
            :nombre,
            :dni,
            :risk, 
            :birth,
            :residencia
          ]
        ])
  end

  def after_invite_path_for(resource)
    new_asignado_path(self.resource.id)
  end
  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may have been this line

```
form_for(setup_user(resource),...
```

I am using a helper to set the HealthRecord of a user to an empty one (fields_for needed the user to have a HealthRecord to work)

```
module FormHelper
    def setup_user(user)
      user.health_record ||= HealthRecord.new # ||= means “assign this value unless it already has a value”
      user
    end
  end
```

Maybe what was happening is that the empty HealthRecord was assigned to the existing user, somehow?

I solved it by intercepting the flow of the create method in the invitations controller, by asking if the user email or dni exists

```
def create
    @correo = User.find_by(email:params[:user][:email])
    @dni = HealthRecord.find_by(dni:params[:user][:health_record_attributes][:dni])
    
    if (@correo.nil? && @dni.nil?) #si no existe mail ni dni
      super
    else
      mensaje="Los siguientes campos ya estan registrados:"
      if !(@correo.nil?)
        mensaje = mensaje + " email"
      end
      if !(@dni.nil?)
        mensaje = mensaje + " dni"  
      end
      flash[:notice] = mensaje
      redirect_to new_user_invitation_path
    end
  end
```

Although this works, I'm not sure about the reason of the problem, any insight is welcome